# Wordpress Query posts that have title > another title

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a query of a custom post type that searches the next 3 posts alphabetical order after a specific title. A snippet of the arguments to `wp_query()` is

```
$vars = array('paged' => $page, 'posts_per_page' => intval($posts), 
  'order' => 'asc', 'offset' => ($offset ? $offset : ''), 'orderby' => 'title' );
```

but have no clue how to query posts where title > specific title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`posts_where`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter to modify where clause of `WP_Query`

```
//create function to handle where clause change
function add_title_clause($where) {
    $titleParam = 'C'; //change it according to your needs

    return $where . " AND post_title > '" . $titleParam . "'";

}


//attach your function to the posts_where filter
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'add_title_clause' );

$vars = array('paged' => $page, 'posts_per_page' => intval($posts), 
  'order' => 'asc', 'offset' => ($offset ? $offset : ''), 'orderby' => 'title' );

$results = new WP_Query($vars);

//remove filter so it does not affect other queries in same request
remove_filter( 'posts_where' , 'add_title_clause' );
```